# Arrangement at the puzzling class

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

PSE open a puzzling class.
16 students join the class.
the classroom have 16 chairs arranged in (4 x 4) grid.

```
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
9   10  11  12
13  14  15  16
```

Students initials are A,A,D,E,E,G,I,M,N,N,O,R,S,U,U, and Y

These are the rules how they are placed in the class.

- Both A are at chairs number 2,5,8 or 12 (take 2 chairs).
- D is at chair number 1,5 or 10
- Both E are at chairs number 3,7,10 or 12 (take 2 chairs).
- G is at chair number 10 or 11.
- I is at chair number 5,13 or 15.
- M is at chair number 3 or 12.
- Both N are at chairs number 1,4,5 or 16 (take 2 chairs).
- O is at chair number 7,11,15 or 16.
- R is at chair number 2,9 or 14.
- S is at chair number 6,9 or 13.
- Both U are at chairs number 1,4,6 or 14 (take 2 chairs).
- Y is at chair number 3,8 or 11.
- Both E must sit in the same row.

> How are they arranged in the class?
>  There is a hidden message in
>   the arrangement.What is the message ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved grid:

> D            A           M           N
>  A            U           O           Y
>  R            E           G           E
>  S            U           I           N

And the message is:

> DAMN YOU ARE GENIUS (if you read it as a snake)

How to solve it without writing a bruteforce algorithm:

> Start with E, the clues are:
>
>  - Both E are at chairs number 3,7,10 or 12 (take 2 chairs).
>  - Both E must sit in the same row.
>
>  And the only possibility here is that E are in places 10 and 12. From here, start eliminating numbers and you will easily find all the other letters